# jQuery scripting; how to reverse text parsing

Tags: jquery

**UPDATE **: Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/cEepx/

I have this code that adds an ellipsis to the end of a text row before wrap:

```
(function (e) {
    e.fn.ellipsis = function (t) {
        var n = {
            row: 1,
            "char": "..."
        };
        return t = e.extend(n, t), this.each(function () {
            var n = e(this),
                r = n.text(),
                i = n.height();
            n.text("a");
            var s = n.height(),
                o = s * t.row;
            if (i <= o) {
                n.text(r);
                return
            }
            var u = 1,
                a = r.length;
            while (u < a) {
                var f = Math.ceil((u + a) / 2);
                n.text(r.slice(0, f) + t["char"]), n.height() <= o ? u = f : a = f - 1
            }
            n.text(r.slice(0, u) + t["char"])
        }), this
    }
})(jQuery);
```

It is applied simply as:

```
$("div.mydiv").ellipsis();
```

How can I modify it to add a second function to remove the ellipsis from mydiv once they are added?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Because I don't see the point.

Comment: That looks like reindented obfuscated code. Do you have the original uncompressed source?

Comment: Original source here: https://github.com/STAR-ZERO/jquery-ellipsis/blob/master/dist/jquery.ellipsis.js

Comment: I am resizing divs on user input and need to remove the ellipsis created, hence my question

Comment: why not using `ellipsis` in CSS property?

Comment: CSS doesn't work when you can't use nowrap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see a direct way to fix it, but you could probably use a hack..

Store the original text as data

```
$("div.mydiv").each(function(){
    $(this).data('origtext', $(this).text())
}).ellipsis();
```

Then use it to reverse the content

```
$("div.mydiv").text(function(){
    return $(this.data('origtext'))
})
```

Comment: Thanks, how would I use this in practice? Should I update the original code or is this a separate script?

Comment: You need to update your original script with the first part then call the second part when you want to reset the values

Comment: @alias51 there were few problems with that see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6tHXV/

Comment: thanks. So if I have more than one div this applies to, what have I missed in this update?: http://jsfiddle.net/kTGpr/